# Function does not exist error message while calling a function in pgAdmin using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following is a function I've created in pgAdmin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_patient(
      patient_id integer,
      name character varying,
      sex character varying,
      "DOB" date,
      phone_number character varying,
      address character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
begin
  INSERT INTO patient
    ("patient_id","name","sex","DOB","phone_number","address")
  VALUES 
    (patient_id,name,sex,DOB,phone_number,address);
  return patient_id;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

However, when I call the function below:

```
SELECT create_patient(nextval('patient_sequence'),'tina','female','2016-12-06','7863334444','541 sw 3 st');
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  function create_patient(bigint, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT create_patient(nextval('patient_sequence'),'tina','fe...
               ^
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I alter the function to insert values effectively?

Comment: Read the error message. You need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's not a good idea to a) use quoted identifiers, b) use the same name for a parameter and a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your sequence is a bigint, but you have your function using the patient_id as an integer.  Either change the sequence to an integer or cast the result of the sequence to an integer:

```
SELECT create_patient(nextval('patient_sequence')::int,'tina','female',
    '2016-12-06','7863334444','541 sw 3 st');
```

On an unrelated note, since you quoted the `DOB` column, it's going to expect quotes and literal uppercase context when you use it.  As such, I think you might need to change your function to this (see comment):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_patient(
  patient_id integer,  -- change this to a bigint if you don't want the cast
  name character varying,
  sex character varying,
  "DOB" date,
  phone_number character varying,
  address character varying) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
begin
  INSERT INTO patient(
    "patient_id",
    "name",
    "sex",
    "DOB",
    "phone_number",
    "address")
  VALUES (patient_id,
    name,
    sex,
    "DOB",   -- right here
    phone_number,
    address);
  return patient_id;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

I'm not 100% sure, but something to watch out for if this fix doesn't fix everything.

Comment: Actually the type of the sequence does not matter, but `nextval()` _does_ return a bigint

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- thanks.  As always, your feedback is helpful and appreciated.  Valerie -- that, at least, explains the "why."  I believe the "how" still applies.  If your sequence will easily remain below Int32.MaxValue it won't matter, but it seems the most technically correct solution is to fix your function to accept a bigint.